# How to redirect with Curl php in the same session

Tags: php, ssl, curl, self-signed, php-curl

Hi I am trying to login to website using Curl php , then I need to redirect to other page and the user should be deleted, and this website is using self sign certificate so far I was able to log In but I am not sure what happen after, therefore the scenario is:

1. Login to url 1 using token, password, name
2. Redirect to  `link2` (`link2` should do an action)

my code look like:

```
$sslCertificate = PATH to ssl certificate 
$$cookie_file_path = PATH TO TXT FILE
$url = mylogin page 
//login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($Header ifno..etc));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERT , $sslCertificate);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $username , $passwrod,$token); 
curl_exec($ch);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($html);
curl_close($ch);
```

Redirect to delete page (I am not sure if its the right way):

```
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url2todeleteUser );
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_SSLCERT , $sslCertificate);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch2);

var_dump($html);
curl_close($ch2);
```

For login it works, but for redirect to the `$url2todeleteUser` , I am not getting any response or error and there is no changes

- I am not sure if I am setting the session in the right way
- is there some previous experience with the same situation or some clear code with steps and details what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You should try using a library slightly higher in the stack and not just an HTTP client. That should make following links, filling out forms, etc. simpler. Like https://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/ or http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks for link, but there any idea regarding using Curl. Bty, also Php browser will use Curl extension https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser

Comment: The problem is not using curl. It is to have the best API to use for your needs. Based on your needs I think you need something higher than just an HTTP client. But of course you could redo everything yourself by hand by just using a bare bone HTTP client.

Comment: Why do you need a CURL for performing redirect? Basicaly, CURL is for performing requests. Redirect - is not a request, its a bit "higher" procedure working on headers layer. Just ```header("Location: $url2todeleteUser");``` is what you are looking for.

Comment: The idea is we are using self sign certificate and I need to go to $url2todeleteUser each time before my testing start to delete the user before the test (I am using Codeception -php), after suffering in the internet there is no clear solution for self sign ssl certificate with codeception , So I want not to open any browser just I want to make Scenario similar to what jemeter do but with Curl for instance , so its possible in Curl to Login to website then same session go to other link ? @VictorPerov

Comment: can you please write me how I will add it to the code ? header("Location: $url2todeleteUser");